# Spreading props in React Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I am trying to go very in-depth to understand the purpose of spreading props in React HOC

So taking the below example;

```
const EnhanceComponent = BaseComponent => {
    return class EnhancedComponent extends Component {
        state = {
            name: 'You have been enhanced'
        }
        render() {
           return ( 
           <BaseComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />   
        )
       }
    }
};

export default EnhanceComponent;
```

Now let's say the usage of BaseComponent is as below;

```
<BaseComponent className='wrapper-container' onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

I assume if had not spread the props in the HOC, we would have been unable to access "this.props.className" OR "this.props.onClick" in BaseComponent. Would that be correct understanding ?

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
         const { className, onClick} = this.props;

         ...
      }
   }
```

Now to use the HOC itself, we would say;

```
const EnhancedMyComponent = EnhanceComponent(MyComponent);
```

And render it as

```
<EnhancedMyComponent className='wrapper-container' onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Now, below are my 2 specific questions;

1. What do we finally render i.e. BaseComponent or EnhancedMyComponent OR using HOC allows us to use either flavor e.g. in some case, if we do not want the enhanced functionality, we just use the base component  ?

OR

```
<EnhancedMyComponent className='wrapper-container' onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

2. Would the props access issue i.e. if we do not spread the props be applicable in both the above cases of consumption i.e. `<BaseComponent />` AND `<EnhancedMyComponent />` ?

Answer (score 1):

***1) What do we finally render i.e. BaseComponent or EnhancedMyComponent OR using HOC allows us to use either flavor e.g. in some case, if we do not want the enhanced functionality, we just use the base component ?***

/ Using HOC allows us to use either flavor. It totally depends where we are wrapping the Component in HOC i.e while exporting or while using it at someplace.

Now, In the below case one has the option to use it with or without HOC

```
// BaseComponent.js 
        class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
                  render() {
                     const { className, onClick} = this.props;
            
                     ...
                  }
               }
    export default BaseComponent;
    
    // SomeComponent.js
    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

    const MyComponent = EnhanceComponent(BaseComponent);
    class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
                  render() {
                     return ( 
                     ...
                     <MyComponent className={...} onClick={...} someExtraPropForHOC={...}/>
                     <BaseComponent  className={...} onClick={...} />
                     ...
                  )
               }
```

To not allow anyone to directly use the Component, wrap it in HOC and export

```
// BaseComponent.js 
    class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
              render() {
                 const { className, onClick} = this.props;
        
                 ...
              }
           }
export default EnhanceComponent(BaseComponent);

// SomeComponent.js
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
              render() {
                 return ( 
                 ...
                 <BaseComponent className={...} onClick={...}/>
                 ...
              )
           }
```

***2) Would the props access issue i.e. if we do not spread the props be applicable in both the above cases of consumption i.e.  AND  ?***

/ Spread the props is needed as HOC does not know what props would be needed for the dynamically wrapped component. So pass all the props which are coming is the only possible way.

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
         const { className, onClick} = this.props;

         ...
      }
   }

class CustomTextField extends React.Component {
      render() {
         const { className, onKeyPress, value} = this.props;

         ...
      }
   }

const EnhancedBaseComponent = EnhanceComponent(BaseComponent);
const EnhancedTextComponent = EnhanceComponent(CustomTextField);
```

Now in this case `EnhancedBaseComponent` and `EnhancedTextComponent` both need different props, but since they are wrapped in EnhanceComponent. It won't know which props to pass. So spread it and send all the props coming to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot...You are quite close to what I am looking for...only thing is for (1), it would have been really great if you could have added some skeletal code for both cases just to be more clear to me.

Comment: You are awesome....A follow-up though...For the 2nd flavor, where you say (To not allow anyone to directly use the Component, wrap it in HOC and export)
I see, you have done export default EnhanceComponent(BaseComponent);

However, in the usage, I see that you have used BaseComponent. 

Am I missing something here ?

                 <BaseComponent className={...} onClick={...}/>

Comment: Thank you. In import, I used the file name BaseComponent itself. It can be named anything. As we import Component without knowing how it is getting exported. We expect it to be BaseComponent while importing without knowing the inner export.

Comment: Oh k...So it is actually the component EnhanceComponent(BaseComponent) which is being imported and used in this case and we are not directly using/consuming the component class BaseComponent

Correct ?